# Windows 7 user profile and "no logon servers available" error

Tags: windows-7

A user called to report his machine running slow running on local domain at his site.  Suspected spyware (he's had it before) and took machine back to my place to run spyware scans as administrator.  Ran scans to clean it, and tried logging in with his credentials at my location to get "There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.", which seems odd because I logged in as administrator of his local domain to run the scans at my site.  I check the user profiles in advanced system settings and see the administrator account fine, but also two "Account Unknown" profiles, one of which I assume is his.

Should I take it back to his site and try logging in again as him and it will clear up automatically when it connects to his domain server or are there bigger problems here?

Comment: Honestly it sounds like the offline profile is corrupt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you removed the machine from a domain environment and it no longer has access to any authentication servers.

When you logged in as the administrator, you probably did so as the local administrator account.

I'd suspect that taking the machine back to the original location will allow you to log in with the user's credentials.

Comment: Yes that worked when I took it back.  I thought that cached credentials would have allowed me to login elsewhere though?..